# Published iOS App does not return IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

recently I published an app in the iOS App Store that contains IAP to unlock app features.
Yesterday, I received an email from an user that said, that the store is empty.
Turns out I have implemented the store but forget to submit my IAP for review. SO I did exactly that, I created a new version and submitted the binary file along with the IAP for review. Both the app and all three IAP were approved a couple of minutes ago.

So I downloaded the app from the store and opened the store - but still nothing. The Sandbox works fine, so I don't know what the error could be?

Has anyone ever seen a similar behavior?

Regards,
inexcitus

Comment: "Both the app and all three IAP were approved a couple of minutes ago. So I downloaded the app from the store" As the email informed you, after approval it can take up to 24 hours for the new version to get working in the store. Be patient.

Comment: Okay I will wait then, I just thought that when the app update os online so are the IAP.

Comment: You would think so. But let's give it some time before we panic. And _then_ we can panic! :)

Comment: The IAP are live, so thanks again. Sometimes the easiest solution is the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!